# Difficult limit questions

Tags: calculus, limits

note that $f\left( r \right) =\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }{ { x }^{ r } } \sin { x } dx$

(a) show that $\lim _{ r\rightarrow \infty  }{ r{ \left( \frac { 2 }{ \pi  }  \right)  }^{ r+1 } } f\left( r \right) =1$

(b) find a real number c and a positive number L for which $\lim _{ r\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { { r }^{ c }\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }{ { x }^{ r } } \sin { x } dx }{ \int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }{ { x }^{ r } } \cos { x } dx }  } =L $

I have no idea about the problem.please give me solutions or hints.

Thanks

Comment: What's the context of these problems?  Do you know Watson's lemma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint for (a):**

Make the change of variables

$$
x = \frac{\pi}{2} e^{-y/r}
$$

and apply the dominated convergence theorem.

**Hint for (b):**

This really boils down to studying

$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} x^r \cos x\,dx.
$$

In this integral make the same change of variables as in part (a) then use the dominated convergence theorem to find

$$
\lim_{r \to \infty} r \int_0^\infty e^{-y} \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} e^{-y/r}\right) e^{-y/r}\,dy.
$$